# How to you select all elements of a sql query row using jquery

Tags: jquery, sql, selector

I have a sql query that uses a while loop to display all of the rows from a table. Each row generates two divs. one for the rows id and the other for the rows name. I want the div with the rows id to show up when you hover over the div with the name.

I got everything working except for the selectors. I'm currently just using simple classes but obviously hovering over any name shows all the id divs, not just the id for the name you're hovering over.

If anyone could explain what would be the best to achieve this effect I would greatly appreciate it.

**PHP**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {

    echo "<div class='id' class='hidden'>" . $row['id'] . "</div><div class='name'>" . $row['name'] . "</div>";

      }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".blue").mouseenter(function() {
       $(".red").removeClass("hidden");
   });
   $(".blue").mouseleave(function() {
       $(".red").addClass("hidden");
   });
   $(".red").mouseenter(function() {
       $(".red").removeClass("hidden");
   });
   $(".red").mouseleave(function() {
       $(".red").addClass("hidden");
   });
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

Comment: if you show some of your code, it could be so easy to answer your question (or create a fiddle at jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

Sample structure:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='div_id' style='display:none;'>id</div>
   <div class='div_name'>name</div>
</div>
<div class='container'>
   <div class='div_id' style='display:none;'>id</div>
   <div class='div_name'>name</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(".div_name").on("mouseenter",function(e){
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.div_id').show();
}).on("mouseleave",function(e){
    $(this).closest('.container').find('.div_id').hide();
});
```

Comment: What is div_id and div_name? are they just place holders or is there someway i can use variables in the jquery string?

Comment: they are just place holder class names...you can use anything you want there.

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<div class='order'><div class='id' class='hidden'>" . $row['id'] . "</div><div class='name'>" .       $row['name'] . "</div></div>";

}
```

jQuery

```
$(".order").on("mouseenter",function(e){
  $(e.target).find('div.id').show();
});
$(".order").on("mouseleave",function(e){
  $(e.target).find('div.id').hide();
});
```